# How can I display buffer data as image in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, multer

How to display image in react.   ...     ..

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getdata= async()=>{
    const response  = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000')
    setData(response.data)
    }getdata()
   }, [])
return (
  <div>
   {data && <img src={"data:image/jpg;base-64,"+data} alt='image'></img>}  
 </div>
 );
}
```

Backend

```
 const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    img:{data:Buffer,contentType:String},
    name:{type: String}
  })
 const imageModel = mongoose.model('images', schema)

 app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
 imageModel.findOne({}, function(err, image) {
 if (err) { return next(err); }
  res.json(image.img.data);
  });
});
```

Response from backend  https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4cSB.png

Answer (score 1):

you can use `image.img.data.toString("base64")` to convert the buffer from the database to base64 representation. So here is what you need to change in your backend:

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  imageModel.findOne({}, function(err, image) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }

  // Replace the buffer array with base64 data
  const imgBase64 = image.img.data.toString("base64");
  image.img.data = imgBase64;

  // Send the object
  res.json(image.img);
});
```

Comment: delete the dash between `base` and `64` for the value of `src` attribute

Comment: Invalid url error GET:data:image/jpg;base64,255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,226,2,40,73,67,67,95,80,82,79,70,73,76,69,0,1,1,0,0,2,2

Comment: because apparently you didn't use the `.toString("base64")` method that I mentioned in my answer, or maybe you used it but you didn't send the converted data to your frontend. What you have in the url is still the buffer array.

Comment: I edited my answer and included the changes you need to do.